# Have git auto commit every file change on server to bitbucket

Tags: git, bash, bitbucket, autocommit

How do I Make GIT auto-commit every file change (centOS)

Is it possible to everytime my webserver has an update made to it, that it automatically updates the bitbucket repository for it.

I've got a developer who is constantly updating the server source code, but he's not making repo commits, is their a way to make the server auto commit when he updates the code on the server so I have a history of what changes have been taking place.

NOTE: This is a development server so security isn't a high priority but it would be nice.

Comment: That's simple: Remove his access to the server and force him to use Git to get changes deployed there (preferably automatically after the push). :->

Comment: Yeah, force him. Make him work out of his own branch and then have him merge all the changes from the main branch into his branch to make sure he doesn't break everything. Also, you can setup a CI system so that every time he pushes to any branch his code gets tested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The solutions in the comments are preferable**. But if you are really desperate, you could write a cronjob to automatically commit all modified files in a directory every minute, hour or day.

Just write a simple script that commits and pushes from the directories you care about -

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/repo/
git commit -a -m "Auto-Commit"
git push
```

Then add the script to your [crontab, CentOS Instructions here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html). Have it run however often you like.

This will only commit files that have already been added to the repository.